# Office Access errors

Tags: ms-office

when Office start, this error appears. Someone help me to resolve?

`MS Office can't find your license this application. A repair attempt was unsuccessful or was cancelled. MS  Office will now exit.`

Comment: Are you sure you paid for it?

Comment: I'm sure. It becomes that when I endtask some services from Taskbar

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you installed from a wrong installer. Try reinstalling and use 64-bit (or 32-bit if you used 64-bit before).

Normally (even for 64-bit systems), the use of Office 32-bit is suggested. 64-bit will sometime's give unexplainable errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Project Pro 2016, then i uninstall all office by tool: o15ctrremove. You could download it from office page [Uninstall Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8)
And install again, now everything work fine! :)
Hope helpful!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using Office, before installing any version of Office, don't forget to create a restore point using System Protection at Control Panel. If uninstalling Office and reinstalling doesn't fix your problem, you might try reinstalling Windows. Just insert your Windows installation media, boot from it, and when setting up your partition format your Windows partition and proceed reinstalling Windows from the partition you've just formatted. At many cases that should solve your problem.